# creating fallback urls from codeigniter to laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

we are using codeigniter as our current framework, but now we are working on laravel to enhance some features, but one of the problem we are facing is to give the fallback for old url use in codeigniter, our current url looks like

www.school.com/index.php/student/subjects/102030

how to convert this to this

www.school.com/students/subjects/102030

having problem dealing with index.php in our urls, as they are indexed in google which would really annoy them, and would be awful with seo

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can actually see what's going on.

Comment: Probably just an RewriteRule set in .htaccess would do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an .htaccess if you are using apache. After some tests something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php\/student\/subjects\/([0-9]+)$ students/subjects/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's making a 301 redirection so the new urls replace the old ones in search engines after a while.